# Как вывести результат деления двух столбцов в третий в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Добрый вечер, коллеги!
У меня есть две серии (is_goal, shot_outcome) в наборе данных с данными типа float и третья серия (rate), которая должна содержать результат деления двух серий. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы можете выложить ваши данные в текстовом виде - например вывод от `print(df.head())` или еще лучще: `print(df.to_dict('r'))`? И что вы хотите  делить на что?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похоже вам надо:

```
df['rate'] = df['is_goal'] / df['shot_outcome']
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо, вы как всегда правы!)Мне как раз и нужно было делить эти две серии